How to vertically reorder events by drag and drop in fullcalendar?
I am using the version 3 of fullcalendar in my PHP project and currently we are already using the drag-n-drop function to change the dates of the events in the non-time-aware views (basicDay, basicWeek and month).
Now I want to be able to manual change event's vertical order by drag'n'drop them.
That'd be a feature such as in Atlassian's Jira Kanban board that it's possible to vertical order the issues by priority (from the top to the bottom).
Is that possible? I couldn't figure it out by reading the documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/event-dragging-resizing.
Also, if this feature is only available in newer versions (such as 6), please let me know!

What do you mean? Fullcalendar displays events based on their starting datetime, so vertical ordering doesn't make a whole lot of sense... JIRA's custom sorting is for ordering Issues/Tickets in a specific order, but that has nothing to do with datetimes, so the comparison also doesn't make a whole lot of sense (to me anyways). Are you asking about how to order multiple events with the same start? Or something else? You might need to edit your question and add some clarification.

The non-time-aware views such as the "basic" view in v3 don't let you drag and drop vertically, because there is no time-slot to drag them onto. In fullCalendar, dragging changes the start date/time of the event. Since in a "basic" view the smallest unit of time deliniated in the view is 1 day, you cannot drag within a day - since there are no smaller time markers it cannnot alter the start time.

I assume this question is in relation to your previous post where you're using a custom eventOrder setting to control the ordering of events which otherwise have the same start time. Unfortunately fullCalendar does not provide any way to re-order such events by dragging (because as I said, dragging is based entirely on changing the start date). It would have no way of knowing how to change your custom level field to a suitable new value based on a drag. So you will have to build some custom UI for that yourself, I think.

Hello @TimLewis and @ADyson thanks for your answers. That's correct, this new question is related to the last one about the eventOrder custom level. I wanted to know if it would be possible to pre-ordering by the level parameter and than let the user reorder it by priority of events. Reading your answers I understood that in the basic view it wouldn't be possible to vertically reorder by drag'n'drop, but would it be possible in other type of views (even if the start time changes)? Would this be possible in v3 or only v6? Regard allDay events (same start), would be possible somehow?

In time-aware views you can re-order things vertically, but you have to drop the event on a specific time, and that will save a new start time for that event. (Or you can drop a timed event into the all-day slot and it will become an all-day event.) An event cannot be dragged from one place to another within the all-day area because, again, that area is not aware of times of day. Check out the demos on the fullCalendar website to see more. This behaviour is the same in v3 and v6. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-dragging-resizing-demo

Thanks for sharing this demo and for all the clarification, it really helped! Will share here later how we are going to proceed in our project. Big thanks again!
